# Using Model Manager on queryset

Tags: python, django, admin

I want to do some functions from my `ModelManager` in my admin panel. I have:

**`admin.py`**

```py
def change_status(modeladmin,request,queryset):
    status = queryset.change_value()
    return status
```

**`model.py`**

```py
class ItemManager(models.Manager):
   @classmethod
   def change_value(cls):
       list = Item.objects.filter(value=5)
       list.update(value=6)
       return list.list_values("id", flat=True)
   

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    value = models.FloatField()

    objects = ItemManager()
```

But I get:

```
QuerySet object has no attribute `'change_value'
```

But queryset is `Item Queryset` so why can't I use manager methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your model.py module like the below:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    value = models.FloatField()

    objects = ItemManager()
    class Admin:
        manager = ItemManager()
```

As we expect just `objects` to be *manager*, but the admin will use `manager` in `self.Admin.manager`.

Reference:
[**`Admin model manager`** <sup>[djangoproject-code]</sup>](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4754)